# Unable to invoke JMeter scripts in PowerShell ADO

Tags: azure, powershell, jmeter, azure-pipelines

Unable to invoke JMeter scripts in PowerShell ADO.
What is the reason? please provide any solution/suggestions for this issue. no information on issue where and why it is failed to find the root cause

> ERROR: Test run has failed

ADO Jmeter Pipeline Snapshot

[image]

Comment: Looks like you have logging disabled for jmeter, you might want to turn that on.